# Facebook like button and page image not showing up correctly

Tags: iphone, fbconnect, facebook-likebox

I am working on having a Like button for a page created on Facebook.
 I followed this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

I applied the code:

```
 NSString *likeButtonIframe = @"<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=122723294429312&amp;width=292&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:62px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>\"";
 NSString *likeButtonHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>%@</BODY></HTML>", likeButtonIframe];

 [(UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:webViewLikeTag] setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10.0, 220, 30.0)];
 [(UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:webViewLikeTag] loadHTMLString:likeButtonHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

It doesn't show my FB Page image or like button. However, if I use the code by the author, it shows both the page and the like button.

The problem is that I don't know which ID I have to put in for the ID parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `id` parameter in the url with the [id of the page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you want to show in the like box.

Comment: hi it tried this approach                                                             NSString *likeButtonIframe2 = @"<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=203066876473959&amp;width=292&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:62px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>\""

Comment: It show my page image as well as the like button but doesnot reflect my like on the facebook page

Comment: Are you logged in as a user? Are you sure this user hasn't already liked the page?

Comment: Hi ,this  is my page url https://www.facebook.com/pages/Vintur/203066876473959              and the code which i got is below Could you please check if i missed something                       <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FVintur%2F203066876473959&amp;width=292&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=168006413313678" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: Looks okay to me, did you check for the things I asked you in my previous comment?

Comment: I am using a seprate account here to like the page  .Are you using the same approach.Could you please provide me the iframe code you are using

Comment: Hi Again.Thanks 4 all your support,I got it working.It was taking few minutes to update on the page .Thanks Alot